# FUNCION SQL QUE REALIZA UNA CONSULTA USANDO EL OPERADOR LIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

estoy intentando hacer una consulta que me retorna un codigo consecutivo para otra tabla, sin embargo requiero hacer una consulta utilizando el operador LIKE y el comodin %, al principio guardaba la consulta en una variable TEXT y ejecutaba la consulta en un for loop, sin embargo cuando necesite el LIKE no me deja realizar la consulta ya que necesito pasarle a la consulta un parametro recibido en la funcion.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_cod_pk(IN cod_curso VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR AS $$
DECLARE 
    asignatura RECORD;
    query_codigo TEXT;
    contador INT;
    cod_simulado VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    query_codigo := 'SELECT cod FROM asignatura WHERE cod LIKE'; -- ACA NECESITO INTRODUCIR LA VARIABLE COD_CURSO
        contador := 0;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Necesito algo como SELECT cod FROM asignatura WHERE cod LIKE '[cod_curso]%'

Comment: ¿Has intentado concatenar la variable?

Comment: Si lo intente de esta manera CONCAT(cod_curso, '%'); el problema es que ese concat va dentro de la cadena de texto por lo cual no se ejecuta creeria. O puedes corregirme si la forma en que concateno esta mal.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes concatenar el valor de la variable, por ejemplo:

```
query_codigo := concat('SELECT cod FROM asignatura WHERE cod LIKE ''', COD_CURSO, '''%');
```

OJO: Si esa variable ha sido introducida por el usuario, debes asegurarte que no contiene valores que ocasionen problemas, de otra manera tu aplicación será vulnerable. Investiga sobre la vulnerabilidad de inyección SQL para más información.

OJO: No recuerdo si Concat soporta más de 2 cadenas, si no lo hace, haz un `concat(concat(...`

Comment: Usuario de postgresql aqui, confirmo que acepta mas de dos cadenas

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza `FORMAT`:

```
query_codigo := FORMAT('SELECT cod FROM asignatura WHERE cod LIKE ''%s''', cod_curso);
```

`%s` se reemplazará por el valor del argumento, y puedes utilizar tantos argumentos como quieras.

Si estás ejecutando el código guardado en esta variable con una variable externa, te conviene usar `FORMAT` también en la parte donde lo ejecutas, pues puedes agregar funciones para evitar la inyección de SQL y para que los identificadores tengan el contexto adecuado.